# How to call async method asynchronously from non-async method

Tags: vb.net, async-await

How do you wait on a task from an async method, in a non-async method, without actually calling the method?

```
Class TestAsync
    Dim workevent As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
    Sub work()
        Dim Task As Task = Test()
        'Do Work which affects Test Here
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        workevent.Set()
        'wait for Test to complete
        'Task.Wait() -causes the application to hang
    End Sub

    Async Function Test() As Task
        workevent.WaitOne()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if possible, never do that. Synchronously waiting for an async method defeats the whole purpose of using async. Instead you should make `work()` into an `Async Function WorkAsync() As Task`. And then make the method(s) that call `work()` asynchronous too, and so on, all the way up.

Second, asynchronous isn't the same as parallel. If you have `Async` method with no `Await`s, it will execute completely synchronously, as if it was a normal method. So, your method will hang even without `Task.Wait()`.

What you can do is to run `Test()` on a background thread using `Task.Run()`:

```
Sub work()
    Dim Task As Task = Task.Run(AddressOf Test)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    workevent.Set()
    Task.Wait()
End Sub
```

The `Task` returned from `Run()` will complete when the `Task` returned from `Test()` completes.

(There are other issues causing hangs when combining `Wait()` and `Async`, but they are not relevant in this specific case.)

But I repeat: you shouldn't do this, since it blocks the UI thread, though it's only for a short while.

Comment: This function is being run in a unit test so it has to stop being async somewhere

Comment: @user1937198 It doesn't, if your unit testing framework supports `Async`. And current versions of most unit testing frameworks for .Net do.

Comment: +1. Current versions of MSTest, xUnit, and NUnit all support `async` unit test methods that return `Task`.

Comment: Not The MSTest that comes with VS2012

Comment: Its version 2 ctp 3 of 2012, is mstest upgradable separately?